# How can I chat with friends while in a LoL match?

Tags: league-of-legends

Is it possible to chat with people on my friendlist while I am playing a match? If so: how? I did not find any window or button for this yet.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can type `/w username message` to message an online friend. If your friend replies to the initial message, you can just type `/r message/`. If you want to send another message without a response, you have to use the /w method again.

The /r method will automatically fill in the username of the friend you are having the conversation with when you start typing the message. (It fills it in with the last user that messaged you)

> /w = whisper
>
> /r = reply

*They have to be on your friend list as well as in the same region as you for this to work.*

If you have a friend that thinks it is fun to spam you during a match, you can use `/mute username`, which will stop chat for your game's duration. I would **not** recommend using `/ignore username` as it will remove your friend from your friend list.

Comment: You can continue to use /r to reply to the same person in succession, even if they do not send you another message.

Comment: Note: if you play LoL in windowed mode, you can chat during loading screen by clicking on the red Riot icon in your system tray to reopen the AIR client. (This does have the unfortunate effect of having the taskbar icon flash whenever you receive a message, which can be distracting in the middle of a game, but that can be mitigated with a 3rd-party tool that enables minimising to tray.)